# Reading lines in C

Tags: c, scanf, gets

I need to read an input. The thing is the input can be `1` or `a` or `1 word1` or `a word1 word2`.

How can I read the entire input? I've tried `scanf("%s", var);` wich only gets the first thing you write. And I can't use `scanf("%s %s %s", var, var2, var3);` since there aren't always 3 variables.

I also tried `gets(var);` and I get `warning: the 'gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.`

How can I do this?

Comment: Use `fgets` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`gets()` is deprecated because it has no way of knowing how big your buffer is. As a result, it can easily overwrite the buffer you give it.

Use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html) instead.

```
char buffer[100];
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
```

Or, if you have allocated memory dynamically, the `sizeof` operator won't help, so you'll need to manually specify the size:

```
const size_t bufferSize = 100;
char *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
fgets(buffer, bufferSize, stdin);
```

Just a small word of warning, the `fgets()` function will read *and store* the linefeed character into your buffer.